# Searchkick::ImportError in Devise::SessionsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to add an API to an existing Rails app, and found myself with an error that i have never encountered before when trying to logout from the application.

The error is as follows:

```
Searchkick::ImportError in Devise::SessionsController#destroy
{"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"} on item with id '1299d9c9-e5c9-4e49-b0ff-b986c415eee8'
```

This has been happening since i started playing with adding API. I added the following controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ActionController::Base
      #before_action :check_basic_auth
      #skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

      private

      def check_basic_auth
        unless request.authorization.present?
          head :unauthorized
          return
        end

        authenticate_with_http_basic do |email, password|
          user = User.find_by(email: email.downcase)

          if user && user.authenticate(password)
            @current_user = user
          else
            head :unauthorized
          end
        end
      end

      def current_user
        @current_user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and a specific controller :

```
module Api
```

module V1
class MicropostsController < ApiController
def index
@microposts = Event.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
render json: @microposts

```
  end
  def show
    @micropost = Event.where(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.xml {render xml: @micropost}
      format.json {render json: @micropost}
      
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

Is there any obvious reason why this would interact with devise please?

Comment: could you add the code for the user model? and also rails logs

Answer (score 0):

After doing more search i found the solution that worked:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```